# Setting up maximum of connections for web

Tags: wildfly

In JBoss7 we've restricted number of web connections by using this

```
<connector name="https" scheme="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="https" secure="true" max-connections="3000">
```

for `urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0` subsystem which is replaced by `urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2` in the wildfly. How to setup `max-connections` in wildfly?

I went through the documentation and didn't find matching attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try add under filters definition

```
<filters>
    <connection-limit name="limit-connections" max-concurrent-requests="3000" queue-size="100"/>
</filters>
```

and then under host or location add (depends on your need)

```
<filter-ref name="limit-connections"/>
```

See a [configuration example](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/undertow/src/test/resources/org/wildfly/extension/undertow/undertow-1.0.xml) and [Model Reference](http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.2.0.Final/subsystem/undertow/configuration/filter/connection-limit/index.html)

Also take a look in Configuring the Web server Pool: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/entering-undertow-web-server.html

Comment: What will be the max-concurrent-requests allowed by default if this filter is not added?

Comment: it is 2,147,483,647 by default. Ref- https://docs.wildfly.org/19/wildscribe/subsystem/undertow/configuration/filter/request-limit/index.html

Comment: @CaffeineCoder Yep I know but question is for jboss7 (tomcat web container) not wilfly undertow.

Comment: @FedericoSierra I think he is asking for WIldfly in his question- ". How to setup max-connections in wildfly?". To answer your question for JBoss, this parameter is undefined which results in unlimited connections.

Answer (score 10):

The above comment from Federico Sierra is correct. But in Wildfly 10.x the filter name 'connection-limit' doesn't exist anymore. Instead it is now called 'request-limit'.

So for Wildfly 10.x add filter reference in the untertow subsystem inside 'server' and 'host' context and the request-limit filter inside the 'filters' context:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
[...]
  <server name="default-server">
  [...]
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
    [...]
      <filter-ref name="limit-connections"/>
    </host>
  </server>
[...]
  <filters>
    <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
    <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
    <request-limit name="limit-connections" max-concurrent-requests="3000" queue-size="100"/>
  </filters>
</subsystem>
```

Reference: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/undertow/src/test/resources/org/wildfly/extension/undertow/undertow-3.1.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit the maximum number of concurrent connections for an HTTP/HTTPS/AJP Connector you have to set the attribute max-connections.
Example:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=max-connections,value=300)
```

Source: [How to set the maximum number of Web connections in WildFly](http://www.mastertheboss.com/web/jboss-web-server/how-to-set-the-maximum-number-of-web-connections-in-wildfly/)

Comment: Do you know the difference between the max-connections and defining a filter?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `max-conncections` attribute as defined in the documentation. Either for [http](https://docs.wildfly.org/19/wildscribe/subsystem/undertow/server/http-listener/index.html#attr-max-connections) and/or [https](https://docs.wildfly.org/19/wildscribe/subsystem/undertow/server/https-listener/index.html#attr-max-connections) connections. It is defined as

> "The maximum number of concurrent connections. Only values greater
> than 0 are allowed. For unlimited connections simply undefine this
> attribute value."

I don't see the benefit of defining an extra filter. But maybe the others can shed some light on this... So similar to the other solutions it would look like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:10.0">
[...]
  <server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-connections="3000" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
    <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" max-connections="3000" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true" />
  [...]       
  </server>
[...]
</subsystem>
```

**Update**: I just realized that this is the standalone.xml solution to what Francesco is proposing...