# Wildfly 8.2 stop incoming connections suddenly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

We have a wildfly 8.2 app server which allocates 6GB of server RAM. Sometime due to havey transaction count wildfly has stop receiving incoming connections. But when I check server (not app server, it is our VM ) memory, it uses 4GB of RAM. Then I checked Wildfly app server's heap memory it did not use at least 25% of allocate heap size. Why is that? When I restart wildfly App server, All things work normally and when it comes that kind of load, above scenario happen again

Comment: Maybe some deadlock occurred due to high-rate concurrency between transactions

Comment: Or you can try to make a  snapshot of threads in JVM (`jstack` tool in JDK) on next "encounter", maybe deadlock occurred there

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the connection-limit as suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825894/setting-up-maximum-of-connections-for-web) 
You can Dump HTTP requests as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715552/dump-http-requests-in-wildfly-8/26807691#26807691)

Also, are you getting any errors in your console? Please post them as well.