# Configuring HTTP thread size in JBOSS eap 7

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I cannot find any documentation for configuring how many requests can be processed by JBoss EAP7 simultaneusly. I see something like HTTP connector and thread pool for 6.4 version but the 7 version misses that:

> 3. Make the HTTP web connector use this thread pool

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.3/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/sect-connector_configuration

So how to configure that for example only 300 requests at one time can be processed and other have to wait for their turn, so that too many simultaneous requests wouldnt kill the server? I know, that my application is effitient enough serving up to 300 requests, after that problems may occur..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up maximum of connections for web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825894/setting-up-maximum-of-connections-for-web)

Comment: Maybe.. how the new io sybsystem is related to it? It is something different than filters and max-concurrent-requests: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/configuring_the_io_subsystem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JBoss EAP7` uses `Undertow` as the default web container, In Undertow by default all listener will use the default worker which is provided by IO subsystem.This worker instance manages the listeners `(AJP/HTTP/HTTPS)` IO threads.

The IO Threads are responsible to handle incoming requests.The IO subsystem worker will provide the following options to tune it further.

You could try the following:
 `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:2.0">
            <worker name="default" task-max-threads="128"/>
            <buffer-pool name="default"/>
        </subsystem>`