# Camunda REST Api usage for starting async BPMN Processe

Tags: wildfly, camunda, camunda-plugin, camunda-spin

We are using camunda subsystem in Wildfly environment.
So we have a deployment for this camunda/wildfly - which runs in a pod and connects to MYSQL for DB.
There will be another application which reads events and based on that calls REST Api of camunda - for starting a BPMN flow.
We have really huge events coming in for that application. like 5-10 events per sec and it has to call Camunda REST APi for starting a BPMN flow.
All our BPMN's are AsyncBefore - at the startEvent.
We have tuned the jobExecutor with below values

```
<property name="queueSize">50</property>
    <property name="corePoolSize">150</property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize">250</property>
    <property name="keepAliveTime">10</property>

 <property name="lockTimeInMillis">900000</property>
<property name="waitTimeInMillis">5000</property>
<property name="maxJobsPerAcquisition">50</property>
```

The issue is even though we have put these values i can see
only max Jobs running/Locked at a time are only 100-110 from ACT_RU_JOB table
I suspect the REST Api not able to handle those many calls.

Do we have any parameters to tune the REST API?

Camunda 7.18 Version and Wildfly 26 is what we are using

Answer (score 1):

The additional threads will also requires database connections. Have you also tuned the DB connection pool? It could be that the thread s are waiting for DB connections. This is not Camunda specific. Generic Wildlfy pages such as https://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-datasource/jboss-datasource-configuration/ may help.

I would also look at configuring the web sever pool as described here:
[Setting up maximum of connections for web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825894/setting-up-maximum-of-connections-for-web)

Comment: Yes I have configured the DB threads in Datasource as well.

Comment: added another aspect to check

Comment: I had configured thread pool size of 50 max threads,
looks that wasn't suffiecient. I doubled it and now i can see there is no lag in REST API